# Google analytics in Wordpress subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, subdirectory

I am converting over a static site to Wordpress. Wordpress is installed in a subdirectory. What I'd like to know is how to add the subdirectory to the current Google Analytics report. I have tried adding both Google analytics asynch and ga.js code into the existing embed code according to the instructions as outlined here-

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#domainSubDomains

...and it isn't showing up on the dashboard.

Is there a straightforward methodology or tutorial for doing this?

Incidentally, I've tried using a plugin to integrate Google Analytics into the site, but it's only showing me the current analytics, without an option for the subdirectory. So, I'm assuming the embed code needs to be modified.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you add your script tag?

Comment: Script tag is added right before end of body tag.